# change figure caption size doesn't work

Tags: beamer, fontsize, beamer-metropolis

I am using this code (metropolis) .

Whatever I used in order to change the figure caption size, doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[10pt] {beamer}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage {graphicx, beamerthemesplit}

\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]
    {\bgroup\greekfont{#1}\egroup} % Greek text

\newenvironment{greekpar}           % Greek paragraph
    {\greekfont}{}


\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\Tiny}
%\usepackage[textfont={small}]{caption}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}

%\DeclareCaptionFont{8pt}{\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont}
%\captionsetup{font=8pt}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\definecolor{mpigreen}{HTML}{007977}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=mpigreen}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow]

\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=alerted text.fg!10}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=alerted text.fg!20}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=structure!10}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=structure!20}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=green!8}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=mpigreen, fg=white}

\newenvironment<>{question}[1]{%
  \begin{actionenv}#2%
      \def\insertblocktitle{#1}%
      \par%
      \mode<presentation>{%
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=mpigreen, fg=white}
       \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=blue!8}
       \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=green!20!black}
       \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
     }%
      \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
    {\par\usebeamertemplate{block end}\end{actionenv}}
    
\title [Data]{Data}
\author {George}
\date {19/04/2021}

\begin{document}  

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Data}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
                
            \begin{question}{Ερώτηση}
                \begin{itemize} 
                \item Ποιος ειναι ...
                                
                \item μπλα μπλα
                
                \end{itemize}
            \end{question}

        
            \end{column}
            
            \begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.5\textwidth]{./11.jpeg}
                \caption{ΜΟ εδώ πολύ μεγάλο}
                \label{fig:mean_spray}
            
                
            
                \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.3\textwidth]{./22.jpeg}
                \caption{Και εδώ τα ίδια}
                \label{fig:nb_diseases}
            \end{figure}
            
            \end{column}
            \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beamer` themes make their own colour/template/font setup, so you should make your changes *after* loading `metropolis`

```
\documentclass{beamer}  

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\Tiny}

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}
Normal text.
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Foo bar baz.}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]